# Como restringuir rutas o url en laravel 5.7 a cada usuario?

Tags: laravel

Hola recientemente he estado aprendiendo laravel pero leyendo la documentación no logre comprender la parte de autentificacón y esto sucede en la parte de restringir rutas a los usuarios. Por ejemplo si tengo un usuario administrador que peude ingresar a estas rutas:

- mipagina.com/registrar-producto
- mipagina.com/editar-producto
- mipagina.com/gestion-producto

Otro usuario cliente que pueda ver los productos y comprar

- mipagina.com/listado-de-productos
- mipagina.com/comprar-productos

Como haría para que el usuario clienta no pueda acceder a las rutas del administrador? Solo necesito algunas teorías o puntos para empezar investigar ya que me siento confundido con esta parte. Logre hacer un login pero cualquier usuario logeado puede acceder a todas las rutas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como ya mencionaron antes, lo mejor es usar un grupo, pero adicional a eso, también es bueno que agregues un alias, un namespace y un middleware especifico para validar el admin.

Todo esto por que generalmente los controladores y rutas del admin deben separarse de las rutas de usuario, y el middleware por que el usuario admin se valida diferente al usuario normal

Todo debe quedar mas o menos así

```
Route::namespace('Admin')
     ->prefix('admin')
     ->name('admin.')
     ->middleware(['auth', 'admin'])
     ->group(function () 
    {
      /*
      Route::get('/', function () {
          // 
      });
      */   
    });
```

De eta forma todas las rutas quedan así:

**mipagina.com/admin/registrar-producto**
se les agrega el admin de forma "automática"

Los nombres de las rutas quedan así:

**admin.registrarProducto**

Y la ruta de los controladores así:

**App\Http\Controllers\Admin**

Recuerda que debes crear el middleware aquí puedes encontrar la documentación al respecto 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware

Acá puedes encontrar un articulo interesante al respecto 
[Laravel Route Tips to Improve Your Routing](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-route-tips-to-improve-your-routing)

Comment: Entonces si dices que se coloca automaticamente, esto quiere decir que tambien debo modificar mis formularios donde especifico la ruta para en envio de los formulario? Gracias por los documentos estuve checando eso pero no entendia muy bien y leere los que me pasaste

Comment: Lo mejor es que no uses las URL si no los nombres de rutas, pero igual tienes que ir a modificar cada formulario.Modifique la respuesta se me olvido poner el de middleware

Comment: Para llamar las url es mejor que uses route('routeName') en el formulario, reemplaza eso. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-route

Comment: Como soy nuevo me cuesta entender un poco como se trabaja en laravel pero te refieres a las rutas del archivo web? debo hacer Route::get('registrar','controllador@index')->name('routeName'); es a esto a lo que te refieres?

Comment: Si exacto, Route::get('registrar','controllador@index')->name('registrar');, esta ruta pasa a llamarse admin.registrar y en el formulario en vez de colocar la url colocas el nombre de la ruta <form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.registrar') }}" accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form">

Comment: La ventaja es que si en un futuro decides cambiar la URL no tienes que ir al formulario y cambiar la ruta, mientras la ruta se llame igual no hay problema

Comment: Creo que ya voy entendiendo y muchas gracias por la ayuda, tengo otra duda y espero que no lo puedas solucionar, para trabajar con esta forma necesito crear mi propio middleware ? para asi ir validando a los usuarios? o como seria? creo que ya logre comprender esto pero ahora me quede en el login

Comment: Si es correcto, lo mejor es crear un middleware que valide si el usuario es admin o no. la facil es crear un campo en user que sea un flag que determine se es admin o no y en el middleware validas si ese flag es true o false y ya.

Comment: si por ejemplo eso es solo para el administrador, y tengo otros usuarios como clientes que deben estar logeados tendria que repetir este mismo proceso?  en este caso ->middleware(['auth', 'admin']) ahora seria ->middleware(['auth', 'cliente']) es un ejemplo...?

Comment: No, creo que para el de clientes puedes manejar solo el middleware auth, ya que ese lo que valida es que estén logueados, pero por ejemplo si necesitas adicionar otra validación, por ejemplo que sean vip, allí si te toca agregar otro.

Comment: Como ultima duda, no entiendo el significado de esto ->middleware(['auth', 'admin'])

Comment: significa que se llama 2 middleware, auth y admin el de auth es el que trae por defecto laravel para validar si un usuario esta registrado, el de admin es el que debes crear.

Comment: Estuve probando lo que me dijiste pero no me funciona y ademas creo que aun tengo dudas, por qué usar el namespace('Admin')?  tambien dentro del ->group(function () 
     {Route::get('/registrar'.'controller@index',}  por que cuando le asigno un nombre y al ir al navegador pongo 127..../admin/registrar la pantalla me muestra en blanco? y si solo dejo el / sin el "registrar" carga la vista

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86714/discussion-between-luis-hernandez-and-soskr).

Answer (score 2):

No especificas la versión de laravel, pero, en cualquier caso, lo más adecuado son los grupos de rutas. (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-groups)

Ejemplo de rutas para el admin exclusivamente:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin',  'middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    /*
    Route::get('/', function () {
        // 
    });
    */   
});
```

Un saludo

Comment: Es bueno aclarar que las rutas del administrador quedaran así mipagina.com/admin/registrar-producto

yo ademas agregaría un alias al grupo


Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin',  'middleware' => 'auth', 'as' => 'admin.'], function() {
    /*
    Route::get('/', function () {
        // 
    });
    */   
});

y para temas mas avanzados, crearía un middleware especifico para validar si el usuario es un admin